# Changing domains in IIS environment

Tags: windows, web, iis, https, server

I am working with `IIS (Internet Information Services )`  in a `windows server` with `URL Rewrite`.

Need to redirect a `URL (https://page.olddomain.com)` to a `new URL (https://page.newdomain.com)`. Everything remains the same, just need to URL to change if a user goes to `https://page.olddomain.com`.

Wondering if I'm following the right process of thought here.

I have a `Inbound Rule` created that *should* work.

> Match URL
>
> Requested URL: Matches the Pattern  Using: Exact Match Pattern:
> https ://page.olddomain.com (ignore case)

No conditions set

No server variables

```
Action 
Action Type: Rewrite
Action Properties 
Rewrite URL: https://page.newdomain.com
Append query string: checked
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Start with mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: I guess the issue is I need keep this page as it has an SSL cert that I need to keep.  Otherwise my users will get the "TURN BACK NOW OR PERISH" page where they need to click advanced and continue to site.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, if you can't implement the redirect step, I think it was caused by the wrong input in `Pattern` box which same with the comment mentioned by Lex Li.

We do not need to input the base url(such as `https://page.olddomain.com`) in `Pattern`, we just need to input the append url after the base url in `Pattern`. For your requirement, you just need to do it as below screenshot:

[image]

I suggest you to use "Regular Expressions" instead of "Exact Match", it can success implement your requirement.

And by the way, maybe you want to input `/` in `Pattern`(just ignore baseurl), but it will not work. So please input `.*` in `Pattern`. Apart from this, you'd better also define a condition to specify the `HTTP_HOST` equal your old host url.

For the comment you mentioned about SSL, I think it will not be affected by the redirect/rewrite rule.